# What happens when a single instance of a class is waiting for a task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core

*Edit: Changed "singleton" to "single instance" because it isn't a real singleton.*

Suppose you have a `DataAccess` class running as a single instance in your application. This one uses MongoDB, but it could apply to anything that has internal async calls.

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private IMongoDatabase _database;

    public DataAccess(IMongoClient client)
    {
        _database = client.GetDatabase("myDataBase");
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsers()
    {
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<User>("users").Find("{}");
        return await collection.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

`DataAccess` is added as a "singleton" in my Startup class's ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSingleton<DataAccess, DataAccess>();
```

And then it is injected into controllers.

Suppose I have thread1 calling DataAccess.GetUsers(), and that's waiting for the result from the ToListAsync method. Now thread2 calls DataAccess.GetUsers() while thread1 is waiting. What happens?

- Is the instance of DataAccess locked by thread1 so thread2 can't start executing the GetUsers method until thread1 is finished?
- Is the instance of DataAccess available and thread2 runs the same collection.Find method while thread1 is also running it?
- Is the instance of DataAccess available but thread2 gets put to sleep when it runs into the ToListAsync method that is already running?

Comment: Sorry, but where is the Singleton? From your code I could call DataAccess constructor as many times as I want.

Comment: I'll update it now. DataAccess is a singleton called by controllers.

Comment: Unless a given type specifically calls out in its documentation that it's designed to be called from multiple threads in parallel, and what the behavior will be if you do so, assume it isn't designed to be called from multiple threads and that will behave unexpectedly and erroneously if you do so.

Comment: @Micteu No, it's *not* a singleton.  It has a public constructor.  There can *absolutely* be more than one instance of it.  That you personally don't intend to create more than one doesn't make it a singleton.  You *forcing* there to be only one is what makes it a singleton, and you haven't done that.

Comment: DataAccess might not suffer from being shared, it's the IMongoClient that is shared across threads which might not be thread safe.

Comment: Why did you not add it as a transient instead of a singelton?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It is added as transient in my actual code. I was just curious what would happen if I switched it to singleton instead.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd The Mongo documentation indicates it can be shared. I should probably have mentioned that it also is set up as a singleton. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/connecting/#re-use

Comment: @Servy so services.AddSingleton is a little misleading, since the class does not necessarily need to be set up to enforce being a singleton within itself for the application to use it as one?

Comment: @Micteu Again, I refer you to my previous comment.  You saying that you're only planning to create one instance doesn't make it a singleton.  You writing the code so that *creating multiple instances is impossible* is what makes it a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2: The singleton available and thread2 runs the same collection.Find method while thread1 is also running it.

This is why when you write a singleton you must make sure the code is safe to run concurrently or in a renterent fashon. Usually this will require putting a `lock` around the resource which turns it from option 2 in to option 1.

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity instead of trying to make me feel stupid because my wording is a little off.